# How to run .NET application on linux with console output?

Tags: .net, ubuntu

The following dotnet test program does not give any output. The console just remains blank:

```
cd ~/Documents/test
dotnet new console
dotnet run
```

The `Program.cs` generated by default:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

And `test.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

What might be wrong, on an `ubuntu 20.04`, with `dotnet` installed version:

```
~/Documents/test$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.102
 Commit:    02d5242ed7

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/155/sdk/6.0.102/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.2
  Commit:  839cdfb0ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.102 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/155/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/155/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/155/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Maybe it's important I installed the SDK via kubuntu "discovery"?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by uninstalling the snap/discovery version, and instead using the microsoft way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-